# no way to change the large icon of my app

Tags: iphone

I submitted an app to apple, they said my icon needs to change.
I redesigned the icon but found that there is no way to change the icon.
If I submitted a new app, the app name will duplicated and be refused

[image]

Welcome any any comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your icon was most likely rejected because it has the iTunes logo in it, which I believe is against Apples policy.

You don't need to submit a "new app" to change your icon. You can just simply change the icon then resubmit the binary.

In your application (in iTunes Connect), choose **Version Information** / *Edit*:

[image]

Then scroll all the way down past the rating system and you will see **Large 512x512 Icon**:

[image]

This is where you will reapply your new icon *(without the iTunes logo)*